# SFDX CPQ : Cannot modify managed object

Tags: salesforcedx, cpq

I am trying to deploy a package including some CPQ objects usiing **sfdx:source:deploy**

I am having the following error :

| API Name | Type | Line | Column | Error Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SBQQ__QuoteTemplate__c | Custom Object | 0 | 0 | Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomEntityDefinition, component=01I3X000001aB7x, field=OptionsFlagEnableLicensing, state=installed |
| SBQQ__Quote__c | Custom Object | 0 | 0 | Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomEntityDefinition, component=01I3X000001aB7z, field=OptionsFlagEnableLicensing, state=installed |

I have tried the following:

1. Retrive the object from org and redeploy it as it was retrieved => I still got the error
2. Deploy using different API version (48.0 to 55.0) => still got the same error with every API version
3. Remove unnecessairy tags from .object-meta.xml => I still got the error
4. Delete the .object-meta.xlm => not getting thd error, but this cannot be done since some metadata in the xml is needed (such as sharing model for example)

Thnak you !

Answer (score 0):

check sharing of the object. We faced this issue due to
Private
while setting it to
Public
has solved the issue.

Keeping in mind, that Salesforce Optimizer Report for
Insecure Default External Access Levels
shows that this setting should be "Private" and not "Public"

and there is another hint mentioned here https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000BmtSQAS
where you should deactivate "Detect Conflicts At Sync" in VSCode.

Hope this hints help..